# What is the correct way, to close the FileHandler from different method

Tags: java, logging

**Goal**

I'm currently logging some SNMP traps with the inbuilt java logging method.

**My Problem**

The problem is, that I'm starting my FileHandler in the constructor of my "Logging" file. Altought the logging itself is taking place inside in a method outside of the constructor.

Therefore I don't know how to close the FileHandler properly after the log took place, because the logger itself opens inside the constructor. -> The error that occures resulting of this, is that my Logging generates Files like "log.txt", log1.txt", "log2.txt"...

**What I tried**

I tried to close the FileHandler at the bottom of my constructor... obviously that didn't work. Also I tried to close it from the method, where the log itself is taking place. The problem here is, that I don't have access to the instance of the handler.

**Logger Code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Logging {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

    public Logging() {
        Logger root = Logger.getLogger("");
        FileHandler txt = null;
        try {
            txt = new FileHandler("log.txt", true);
        }       
        catch(SecurityException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        root.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        txt.setFormatter(new Formatter() {

            @Override
            public String format(LogRecord record) {
                String ret = "";
                /*
                if(record.getLevel().intValue() >= Level.WARNING.intValue()) {
                    ret += "Error: ";
                }
                */
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy | HH:mm");
                Date d = new Date(record.getMillis());
                ret += df.format(d);

                ret += this.formatMessage(record);
                return ret;
            }
        });
        root.addHandler(txt);
    }

    public void addMessage(String message, String type) {
        if(type == "warning") {
            log.warning(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to close the FileHandler, the LogManager will do it for you if you added it to a Logger, which you did.

The LogManager uses a shutdown hook to close all handlers, here is an implementation from openjdk:

```
// This private class is used as a shutdown hook.
// It does a "reset" to close all open handlers.
private class Cleaner extends Thread {

    private Cleaner() {
        /* Set context class loader to null in order to avoid
         * keeping a strong reference to an application classloader.
         */
        this.setContextClassLoader(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // This is to ensure the LogManager.<clinit> is completed
        // before synchronized block. Otherwise deadlocks are possible.
        LogManager mgr = manager;

        // If the global handlers haven't been initialized yet, we
        // don't want to initialize them just so we can close them!
        synchronized (LogManager.this) {
            // Note that death is imminent.
            deathImminent = true;
            initializedGlobalHandlers = true;
        }

        // Do a reset to close all active handlers.
        reset();
    }
}
```

You can use shutdown hook too if you want to manage file-closing at the end of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you can go through, [Examples for java.util.logging.FileHandler](http://www.javased.com/?api=java.util.logging.FileHandler) ?

```
public synchronized static Logger getLogger(){
  if (null != logger) {
    return logger;
  }
  logger=Logger.getLogger("TokenVendingMachineLogger");
  FileHandler handler;
  try {
    handler=new FileHandler("MyLogFile.txt",true);
    SimpleFormatter formatter=new SimpleFormatter();
    handler.setFormatter(formatter);
    logger.addHandler(handler);
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
  }
 catch (  SecurityException e) {
    System.err.println("Security exception while initialising logger : " + e.getMessage());
  }
catch (  IOException e) {
    System.err.println("IO exception while initialising logger : " + e.getMessage());
  }
  return logger;
}
```